# How can I get this Digital painting effect in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I am interested in being able to edit a portrait, getting this effect. I would like to make it look soft, like a drawing. Could you please help me?

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Please see [this post about how to ask about getting certain photo effects](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions), and edit your question appropriately. Doing so will both increase your chances of getting helpful answers _and_ make the question more useful to future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: What effect specifically. What have you tried?

Comment: Its soo softning and artistic,shiny etc...I want this like effect

Comment: http://www.tamilnow.com/movies/actors/ajith/ajith-stills-7224.html

Comment: Please edit the question to include that -- and also, describe those words more. "Artistic" could mean _anything_. And where do you see the other effects? Is it the "halo" of light? The strange smoothness to the beard? The sunglasses?

Comment: And I'm not sure how the second photo relates, because _that's entirely different_. If you see something in common, please explain it.

Comment: @mattdm the subject is the common think between the two images!

Comment: Why those people vote down my Question?

Comment: Why did people downvote? Because your question is unclear and does not describe the effect you want and you aren't helping us understand it any better by editing as suggested. Seriously, the comments I made aren't to be pedantic: they are you help you get better results here.

Comment: okay! can you explain me what effect  this above picture?

Comment: No, we can't because we don't know which of the many effects in the picture you're interested in. Could you give some more examples of pictures showing the effect you're interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a research on youtube and I found this video: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tWSAc03vPe8. I tried to find the whole video which has about an hour duration, but I did not find it. Maybe you can find it. However, if you do some more specific research using similar keywords, you will suit your own expectations in a much better way! There are a lot videos of this kind. You can search them, having in mind what you are actually looking for, because there are different techniques and several versions of one particular technique.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My pleasure, Sathya! Please come back to the site whenever you have any other questions!

Comment: Sure Morpho! I see Your Profile.. Great!!

Comment: @Morpho - ideally an answer should include details about how to achieve the desired result in addition to any links to external sources.  If you could summarize what the video said to do (in your own words) then this would be a much stronger answer.

Comment: I just made a quick research and found this video. Since the the person who asked the question is satisfied, I am pretty happy! :)

Comment: @Morpho  can you help me for this Question http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49390/how-to-get-clarity-picture-from-existing-picture